# What type of "NaN" does this Python Pandas dataframe column have?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

So, I have a Pandas dataframe, and wish to iterate upon a column, doing stuff on the NaNs. 
Issue is: no direct comparison wants to give me a True.

Checking the column via isna() and notnull() works perfectly, and returns the column with proper boolean values assigned.

However, I wish to iterate upon it, using a for loop to check each row. 
In the process, one of the comparisons done is upon "nan" values... And never compares as True.

After Isolating the problem I tried the nans that I *could* think of, but:

```
nans_to_check = [np.nan, None, np.NaN, math.nan, "nan", "NaN"]

for possible_nan in nans_to_check:
    if test_df[0] == possible_nan:
        print(f"{possible_nan} works")
    else:
        print(f"{possible_nan} and {test_df[0]} are NOT the same.")
```

Never prints the "True" output.


I also tried the Pandas "NA" value, which gave me the error of NA being an ambiguous value. If my NaN was that, it'd probably break on the check regardless so that can be discarded as well.

I am now completely and utterly stuck. 
What is going on? 
Is it something with the way Pandas handles NaN or do I just need to keep on trying?

Comment: You're using `if test_df[0] == possible_nan`. But NaN does  _not_ compare as equal to itself, so this comparison is not true.

Comment: Ok, it took me a while to get what you were saying, so NaN == NaN is False. Then what would be the appropiate way of checking for it? The Pandas checks (what google and chatGPT pointed at) only work on dataframes.

Comment: It is important to consider why you are checking for NaNs. make example & explain https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There is usually an `isNan()` function provided somewhere, variously spelt.